# No provider for kf found in NodeInjector

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, firebase

i have upgraded my angular project 8.0 to 9.0 as well all the dependencies and node_modules.But later when i'm try to run the project its compiling successfully but there are no UI showing on browser, and on console i'm getting this error'No provider for kf found in NodeInjector'. i have searched almost everything but failed to get fruitful answers. How can i solve this ?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReYAO.png)

Comment: Do you have kf named service anywhere in your code?

Comment: No i dont have any kind of service named 'kf'.  i think the problem is with the core theme. the core theme is not installed thats why i might have this rendering problem

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.